# scrollIntoView doesn't work with behavior smooth

Tags: javascript, webapi

I'm  trying to learn interSectionObserver and ScrollIntoView in javascript
but ScrollIntoView works odd

```
targetToScroll.scrollIntoView(); // works
//code below does not work on chrome v99.0.4844.74 and does not work on edge 99.0.1150.39, but works on firefox v98.0.1
// targetToScroll.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

for online testing checkout my pen [My pen](https://codepen.io/mosi3883/pen/yLpewga)
javascript file line **11 to 14**

Comment: It works for me! Did you check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility)?

Comment: doesnt work on Google Chrome v99, but works on firefox!

Comment: I see it in Chrome. I wonder if it's related to [this open Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1299237&q=scrollintoview&can=2)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is strange. It works in Chrome v96

Comment: well, i dont know what to say, the code here (https://codepen.io/mosi3883/pen/yLpewga) . the targetToScroll.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}); does not work on chrome v99.0.4844.74 and does not work on edge 99.0.1150.39, but works on firefox v98.0.1

Comment: Just me?........

Comment: No, in Chrome v99 it also doesn't work for me